# MDX SSAS - Max Date in Measure

Tags: mdx, cube, ssas-2008

Just need to get MAX date in ALL my Measures in the Cube. For instance, `DateID` is a `Dimention`, `[Measure].[First Measure],...,...,[Second Measure]`.

How to get list of `MAX(DateID)` from all Measures in my Cube.

Comment: Do you mean the last `DateID` that has a value for any measure? And I would assume `DateID` is not a dimension, but an attribute (possibly the key attribute of the `Date` dimension). Is that correct?

Answer (score 5):

The following will get you the max date value associated with each measure...but you will have to manually create a calculated member corresponding to each measure.

```
WITH
    MEMBER [Measures].[Max Date - Internet Sales Amount] AS
        TAIL(
            NONEMPTY(
                [Date].[Date].[Date]
                ,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
            )
            ,1
        ).Item(0).MemberValue
    MEMBER [Measures].[Max Date - Reseller Sales Amount] AS
        TAIL(
            NONEMPTY(
                [Date].[Date].[Date]
                ,[Measures].[Reseller Sales Amount]
            )
            ,1
        ).Item(0).MemberValue
SELECT
    {
        [Measures].[Max Date - Internet Sales Amount],
        [Measures].[Max Date - Reseller Sales Amount]
    } ON 0
FROM
    [Adventure Works]
```

If you want to get the single max date across all measures in the cube, you'll need to take a different approach.

Comment: lovely format Bill - looks like it has been through `MDXStudio`

Comment: ;-) afraid it's just me being OCD in SSMS