# SSAS Cube Calculation for Max Date

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx

I'm trying to build a Power BI file from a SSAS Cube and we need to have a last modified date based on the last call logged on a table. I'm new to MDX and already tried to use MAX() and that just returns null.

Thanks,
Sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a calculated member, use a measure with the max function and it will correctly show the last date.

Answer (score 0):

Something like below might help you:

[image]

Comment: I've tried Max([Fact Phone Data].[Call Date].Members, [Fact Phone Data].[Call Date].currentmember.Member_Key), but the date is in the last month(9/9/2018) and I've data   up until (10/20/2018

Comment: Is the only way to get a max date value by using a integer date field?

Comment: No, when the dates are stored as integers, they serve the purpose of a key as well as the value.

Comment: Would you by chance to know how to get a max date based on a date type?

Comment: The following link might help you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18598669/mdx-ssas-max-date-in-measure